# The future of iFrames

Tags: iframe

I am about to develop a web site for data entry. It will have hundreds of data entry pages. Previously i have made extensive use of iFrames from the menuing system.

Is this now best practice, i number of developers i have mentioned this to have questioned the use of iFrames saying there are better techniques now. However no one could give me a reason not to use the iFrame.

Does anyone have some opinions on the use of iFrames and the reason i should not use them? If not an iFrame then what?

Comment: The obvious question is why do you think you need to use frames?

Answer (score 0):

An iFrame is to embed foreign content, another site or another page of your site. Web is not only about what you see but about semantic meanings.
Using iFrames is the most effective way to kill your ranking in search engines and also to difficult web browsing since a browser cannot tell what part of the content represents what or how they are related to each other.
For instance, navigate into an iFrame based page and bookmark an internal page, then come back through the bookmark and see the results.
Do a search in Internet and there are many more explanations about this.

Comment: True, but the question doesn't sound like it's trying to optimize it's search ratings, so much as provide an interface to enter data.

Comment: Well, still the accesibility issues are present. An also, remember, since the iFrame use is discouraged and kind of “deprecated” for layout. We cannot anymore be sure if all sites will be rendered the same and if the browsers will behave the same with iframes for layouts.
For example, I have seen many broken iFrame layouts of sites that were made in a time where the inner content would make an iFrame expand to fill its container area.
Although that scenario can happen with any element, I think it is more probable with iFrames for layout since their are discouraged for that.

Comment: Html forms provide interfaces to enter data. Where does a frame come into the picture at all? It sounds like he's using the accursed 1990s technique to simulate master pages.